# How to migrate user and organization in chef-server to newly created chef server?

Tags: chef-infra

I am using standalone chef-server now. I got a issue to change the server, so I followed the process stated in here: https://www.ameir.net/blog/archives/326-migrating-from-one-chef-server-to-another.html

The problem is there is no way to use existed user and organization in new  chef server. The workaround I found is to make new user and add existed key to the user. I think it's not a proper way to do what I want, and even more organization is not available for this way.

I think when chef-server create new user and organization, if it has some way to add existed key by parameter, that's enough.

Is there any way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chef-server-ctl backup` to generate a backup and then restore it to the new server.

Comment: I found that it does not backup what I said (user, organization).

Comment: I think you tried a different tool, the page you linked is showing the outdated `knife-backup` gem. That is unrelated to `chef-server-ctl backup`.

Comment: @coderanger2 Oh, I did not notice that CLI. Thank you for guide. But I have another problem by doing that command. `chef-server-ctl show-config` has old fqdn, vip, ca...